# Why does activity not display the first view in Framelayout, but wait 10 seconds and then display it in Framelayout?

Tags: android

Why does activity not display the first view of the Sexdom object's in Framelayout, but it waits 10 seconds and displays only MainWindow. 's in framelayout?

private FrameLayout frameLayout = null;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    frameLayout = new FrameLayout(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(frameLayout);
    SexDom sexDom = new SexDom(getApplicationContext());
    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow(getApplicationContext());
    frameLayout.addView(sexDom.getView());

    SystemClock.sleep(10000);

    frameLayout.removeAllViews();
    frameLayout.addView(mainWindow.getView());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing to clarify here is the [activity lifecycle.](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#lc) Here we can find that `onCreate` has the task to create the activity view, but the activity will not be displayed until `onStart` is called. From here, we can deduct that a long processing task (like `SystemClock.sleep(10000)`) that will keep the system busy is not good in this method (this can be generalised to any method that runs on `MainThread`) because it will delay the creation of the activity, showing a white screen (until the long task is finished) instead of your actual content view.

Basically, you wanted something like this:

```
1. The activity is created and displayed
2. Add the first view
3. Wait for 10 seconds
4. First view is removed
5. And then add the second view
```

but ended up with something like this:

```
1. The activity is created
2. Add the first view
3. Wait for 10 seconds
4. Remove first view
5. Add the second view
6. Activity is finished creating
7. Activity is displayed with second view by default
```

The key here is to let the `MainThread` continue the creation of the activity without interacting with it. If you still want to switch between those view after a given delay you can use a [`Handler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        frameLayout.removeAllViews();
        frameLayout.addView(mainWindow);
    }
}, 10000);
```